# JVM crash - Problematic frame: [libc.so.6+0x14e156]

Tags: java, opencv, jvm, leptonica

I started facing the following JVM crashes during my integration test build:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f74e1add156, pid=17603, tid=0x00007f743ff9e700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_162-b12) (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.162-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x14e156]
```

I use JNA wrappers for OpenCV and Leptonica libraries.

What can be a reason for this and how to fix it?

**UPDATED**

This is `hs_err_pid18951.log` - https://files.fm/u/s9vnpw3d

I also suspect(but not sure right now) that this issue relates to parallel execution of OpenCV/Leptonica logic inside of the following code block:

```
  Arrays.stream(fileList).parallel().forEach(f -> {
        // OpenCV/Leptonica logic
  }
```

Does it make sense and if so, how it can be fixed?

Comment: What is your app doing? Are you using JNI?

Comment: yes, I use Java JNA wrappers for OpenCV and Leptonica

Comment: Can you run in debug mode and check the full stack trace? Maybe it sheds a light. It must be something to do with the libraries I think.

Comment: This means there is a bug in the JVM code itself or some native code.

Comment: I have enabled debug mode but it doesn't show any meaningful information. Also, I have updated my question and added hs_err_pid18951.log Maybe it will help to find the reason for the crash.

Comment: How to fix it? I've run into the same problem. I use JNA, OpenJDK 11.0.2